# Spring web service vs Axis2 web service

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, spring-ws

My last application had Axis2 web service and used contract last approach. We had a new requirement for creating a web service and I used Spring Web service. A discussion came up in the meeting that why use Spring WS when we already have the required Axis2 libraries to create new web service. I was convincing my team because Spring has Contract first approach which is the best way of creating and all other best points mention in the chapter 2 of the documentation.

But their point was Axis 2 also has contract first.

I would really appreciate anyone since I am really new to web services and still learning what is the difference between Axis 2 and Spring WS. I like an elaborate answer for our better understanding.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your team already has experience with CXF, and it fits the contract-first requirements, then stick with it.

Spring-WS is simpler and more flexible than CXF, in my experience, but that's not an especially compelling reason to switch to it.